# What are Barovian inhabitants' attitudes towards Mongrelfolk?

Tags: dnd-5e, curse-of-strahd

Barovia has a number of different settlements and populations:
Barovia, Vallaki, Krezk, Ravenloft, the Vistani, Mongrelfolk

> and werewolves

Are there details of what each of the populations know about Mongrelfolk and their attitudes towards them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Strahd's Opinion

The entry on Cyrus Belview in section K lists him as "Strahd's faithful servant." Nothing else is said, so we don't know Strahd's opinion of him, aside from allowing him to occupy the castle and serve him.

### Barovians

Barovians in general don't have anything mentioned about mongrelfolk in the Barovian Lore section (p 26).

### Village Barovians

These ones don't get a lore section (so sad for them).

### Vistani

Vistani also don't mention the mongrelfolk in the Vistani Lore section (p 28).

### Vallakians

Again, no mention in the Vallaki Lore (p 96).

### Krezks

In the Krezk Lore section of chapter 8 (p 146):

> Some of the clergy ..., while others went mad and either starved themselves to death or turned to cannibalism.

The people of Krezk seem to think that Mongrelfolk are mad cannibals.

In the abbey in section S, most mongrelfolk are

> locked up because they can't be trusted to wander about unsupervised

So it's reasonable to say the Abbot doesn't have a high opinion of them.

### General Opinion

Mongrelfolk in Appendix D (p 234):

> ***Outcasts***. Mongrelfolk are seldom welcome in other humanoid societies, where they are abused, enslaved, or shunned. They typically live on the fringes of civilization in ruins, deserted buildings, or other places that humanoid races once lived in or built.

Most people don't take kindly to the Mongrelfolk, supported by the very little information we gain from the above lore. But that's all we get out of the Curse of Strahd book.